# What it means to set your head equal to a Node* ptr in a linked list?

Tags: c++

So I am solving a problem
and we cannot use a dummy node

So the code starts like

```
void LinkedList::deletemiddleNode()
{
    Node *pointer = head;
    ...
}
```

The reason why I am confused is because I am confused conceptually. Since we don't have a dummy node, the header Node's prev is set to `NULL` and the tail Node's next is set to `NULL`.
So in a drawing how would you describe what that pointer points to. Like is it a pointer that points to head? Then 
pointer->prev->next would not be able to be used since head's prev is `NULL`, but the example solution uses it...?

Comment: you said it. you are confused conceptually! read about linked lists: what they are, how they work.. etc... and then you will understand the answer to this...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing you said? How about something like this:

Lets say you have variable `head` that points to a `node` object somewhere in memory. It looks something like this:

```
+------+      +------------------+
| head | ---> | some node object |
+------+      +------------------+
```

Then you declare another pointer, named `pointer` and assign to it the *value* from `head`. Now `pointer` contains the same value as `head` and so points to the same node in memory:

```
   +------+      
   | head | ---.
   +------+    |     +------------------+
               >---> | some node object |
+---------+    |     +------------------+
| pointer | ---'
+---------+
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: thanks 
I did review it but the way the question was asked tripped me

Answer (score 0):

the above statement means that you are setting or initializing your head pointer to point to some node object and the head is of the same user defined data type as the Node is !!!